# How to increase Image Memory using Bitmap Factory option

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bitmap

I want to use Big Size Image In Back Ground so How Can I do And i want to It's Working For All Device

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, I guess that you are getting image from server end. Some time big size Bitmap throw `OutOfMemoryException`. So do one thing. Use this library to compress image and then show it to ImageView.

**https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor**

You can also use Library. It provide you facility to fix image size and quality. so it won't be problem for you.

**[Nostra Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)**